# Order by date without year

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to organize the dates without considering the years at all. It would order using the month and day only, sequentially, like a calendar, using order by.

For example, instead of this:

```
17-JUN-03  
10-JAN-05  
22-JAN-07  
03-MAY-08
```

I want this:

```
10-JAN-05  
22-JAN-07  
03-MAY-08  
17-JUN-03
```

Hopefully the question is clear. I'll clarify anything in the comments if I've missed anything.

Comment: If your table size is small enough, you can convert all the dates into the same year, then order by date - performance is probably lousy, but wouldn't matter for a small table. So you'd be sorting `10-JAN-99, 22-JAN-99, 03-MAY-99, 17-JUN-99`

Comment: Or `order by month(dt), day(dt)`, or whatever the applicable Oracle syntax is. Might be `to_number(to_char(dt, 'MM')), to_number(to_char(dt, 'DD'))`, but I wouldn't swear to it...

Comment: order by EXTRACT(month FROM order_date), EXTRACT(day FROM order_date)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try to implement them

Answer (score 5):

you could do something along the lines of:

```
Select YourDate
From YourTable
Where YourConditions
order by to_char(YourDate,'MMDD')
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this was the answer I needed. I was dumb and didn't think of converting to numerical values to order. Thanks!