# Execute PostgreSQL function in Prisma without using $queryRaw

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I've searched in the documentation of Prisma, but I couldn't find any information on how is possible to execute a PostgreSQL function like "**to_char**" using the prisma client.

In short, I would like to execute a query in which I order the data by month and day excluding the year, and all this done by the prisma client, **without using raw query**.

The question would be, if is there any possibility to implement this without using raw query?

While searching on the internet for solution, found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082740/7262058) in raw query.

```
Select YourDate
From YourTable
Where YourConditions
order by to_char(YourDate,'MMDD')
```

I've managed to implement this by using $queryRaw method from prisma:

```
this.prismaService.$queryRaw(
Prisma.sql`
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE to_char(birthdate, 'MMDD')>=to_char(NOW(),'MMDD')
ORDER BY to_char(birthdate,'MMDD')`
)
```

I was hoping to have some kind of function/operation available by Prisma to be able to make the query somehow in this way:

```
this.prismaService.user.findMany({
  where: { birthdate: to_char(new Date(), 'MMDD') },
  orderBy: { birthdate: { gte: { to_char(birthdate, 'MMDD') } } },
})
```

Appreciate any information!

Comment: Hi Birtalan Robert, At the moment, You would only be able to do this with Prisma Raw Query function. There is a feature request to support raw sql functions [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5761)